Handling Asynchronous Keycloak Authentication in React
I'm integrating Keycloak into my React application using the @react-keycloak/web library. I have a PrivateRoute component that should restrict access based on user roles and authentication status. However, I'm encountering an issue where, upon refreshing the page, the authenticated property of the Keycloak object is initially false while Keycloak is checking the user's authentication status. This causes my PrivateRoute component to incorrectly redirect users to the home page.
Here’s the current implementation of my PrivateRoute component:
import React from 'react';
import { useKeycloak } from '@react-keycloak/web';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function PrivateRoute({ children, roles }) {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

  const isAuthorized = () => {
    if (!keycloak.authenticated) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!roles || roles.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }

    return roles.some(
      (role) => keycloak.hasRealmRole(role) || keycloak.hasResourceRole(role)
    );
  };

  if (!isAuthorized()) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return children;
}


After a page refresh, the authenticated property is false until Keycloak completes its check. This results in the user being redirected to the home page, even if they are actually authenticated
How can I handle the asynchronous nature of Keycloak’s authentication check in my PrivateRoute component? I want to ensure that users are not incorrectly redirected while waiting for Keycloak to complete its authentication check. Additionally, how can I implement a timeout to handle cases where Keycloak takes too long to initialize?

Follow this  tutorial : I was experiencing the same issuer and resolved it using the method and logic used in there. https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo.
